# How to represent dynamic query in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @sql_code varchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @repeats INT = 4;

WHILE @i <= @repeats

BEGIN
    SET @sql_code = @sql_code+'SELECT ''foo'+cast(@i as varchar)+''' as bar UNION ALL '
    
    SET @i = @i + 1
END;

SET @sql_code = LEFT(@sql_code,LEN(@sql_code) - 10)

exec (@sql_code)
```

,which when run in SSMS produces this:

```
bar
----
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
```

How can I reproduce the same result as view (dynamically)?

I know you can't use declarations in view, but could it be done through stored procedure or function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dynamic sql inside a view. But yes you can create table valued User-Defined functions as mentioned in this post.

Link to the post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3cdeda6c-af19-46e9-b89f-e575fecd475b/dynamic-query-in-view?forum=transactsql

Answer by Gavin Campbell should give you the idea of what can be done.

**Note** : For more information on Table valued User-Defined Functions: Visit this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191165(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks Utsav. I have seen exactly the same Gavin Campbell's post you linked. My problem is that in that example the core code is SELECT statement and I fail to move from EXEC (end of my code) to SELECT. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, despite what Utsav's good answer says, you can do anything if you put your mind to it.

While this is generally not recommended (this answer is for informational purposes), there are certain use cases where it makes sense to use [`OPENQUERY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) inside a View. `OPENQUERY()` allows you to execute raw SQL against a remote or local SQL Server. Either in the raw SQL itself, or probably more organized in a stored procedure, there's essentially no limitations on the queries you can run, including dynamic SQL.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RunSomeDynamicSQL
AS

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'
    SELECT 1 AS Foobar;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeViewThatExecutesDynamicSQL
AS

SELECT Foobar
FROM OPENQUERY
(
    LocalServerName,
    '
       EXEC YourDatabaseName.dbo.RunSomeDynamicSQL
       WITH RESULT SETS
       ((
           Foobar INT
       ));
    '
);
GO

SELECT Foobar
FROM dbo.SomeViewThatExecutesDynamicSQL;
```

You'll notice I'm using the `WITH RESULT SETS` keyword when executing my procedure inside of `OPENQUERY()`. This is because `OPENQUERY()` needs to know the shape of the result set from the executing query. This is one way to describe that when executing a procedure.

One use case for using `OPENQUERY()` in a View is so you can maximize your ability to performance tune your query (e.g. inside a stored procedure) without losing consumability of the database object.

---

One important fact about using `OPENQUERY()` is that the SQL Server Engine always estimates the cardinality of the results to be 10,000 rows. This means if your result set is much larger than 10,000 rows, for example 10 million rows, then you may not get the most optimal execution plan to serve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Also, despite my informational answer, you can of course use a stored procedure alone if that's sufficient for your use case.

> could it be done through stored procedure

Sure, just wrap a stored procedure around your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeStoredProcedure
AS

DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @sql_code NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @repeats INT = 4;

WHILE @i <= @repeats

BEGIN
    SET @sql_code = @sql_code+'SELECT ''foo'+cast(@i as varchar)+''' as bar UNION ALL '
    
    SET @i = @i + 1
END;

SET @sql_code = LEFT(@sql_code,LEN(@sql_code) - 10)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_code
```

Note I changed the last line of your code to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) because it minimizes your risk for SQL injection issues. You should always use that procedure for dynamic SQL execution instead of directly executing your SQL string.

Comment: Ok, but how do I use this procedure in View? If I write "SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeStoredProcedure" I get error 'Invalid object name 'dbo.SomeStoredProcedure''

Comment: @Monardo It was unclear what your requirements were. It sounded like just a standalone procedure is what you wanted. Please see my other answer if you need to execute a procedure or dynamic SQL inside a View. I will delete this answer once you comment on my other answer.